# Adding tags to mongodb records from flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, post, flask, pymongo

I am working on a hobby app with Flask and PyMongo to render mongodb records in a browser.

It's a database of wikipedia edits and the records look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ff1c0d0dec94126a2000000"),
    "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Us_declaration_independence_signatures.jpg/350px-Us_declaration_independence_signatures.jpg",
    "unvandalism" : "<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">53</span>.  [[Arthur Middleton]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">54</span>.  [[Button Gwinnett]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">55</span>.  [[Lyman Hall]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">56</span>.  [[George Walton]]</div>",
    "delta" : 0,
    "date" : ISODate("2012-07-02T00:44:57.781Z"),
    "offender" : "24.119.187.78",
    "reverter" : "Chillin411",
    "anon" : true,
    "vandalism" : "<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">54</span>.  [[Arthur Middleton]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">55</span>.  [[Button Gwinnett]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">56</span>.  [[Lyman Hall]]</div>], [<div>:<span class=\"diffchange diffchange-inline\">57</span>.  [[George Walton]]</div>",
    "time" : 1341189897781,
    "diff_url" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=500257674&oldid=498121414",
    "date_str" : "Mon, 02 Jul 2012 00:44:57 GMT",
    "page" : "Signing of the United States Declaration of Independence"
}
```

I want to be able to have a text field associated with a record that will allow users to add a tag to that record. So I know it should be an update/upsert POST action here using some form in the template. But I am getting stuck on the basic way of implementing this insofar as getting the context for each record and saying "Take this record here and update it's tag where the user has submitted a tag and clicked submit". I am over thinking it.

What's the most practical way to get this implemented given the existing setup?

Comment: If user is clicking on href to edit record, you can create url like this ``<a href="/edit/{{ record._id }}">{{ record.page }}</a>``. And check for id in view. ``import bson``, ``id = bson.ObjectId(id)``. Then you can update tags in that concrete record, like in @mayhewr answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for [pymongo help](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update), [MongoDB help](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pushAll) or [Flask help](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form).

Maybe this code snippet will help you...

```
from flask import request

tags = request.form.get('tags', []) # Where tags is a list of new tags

mongo_collection.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId('4ff1c0d0dec94126a2000000')},
    {'$pushAll': {'tags': tags}},
    )
```

Comment: Cool, yeah that helps. I guess the only thing I am still not sure about is, since I have multiple records just like that which I am displaying as a list, how to pass back to the snippet above the specific record that I am interacting with in the browser when adding a tag.

Comment: For each record in the list, you can also include the id in the form as a string. Then change the above `update()` call to `{'_id': ObjectId(request.form.get('_id'))}`